# Parametrization of surfaces gauss

Tags: differential-geometry

What is pde relating $f$ and $g$ if the Gauss curvature is $+1$ and $-1$ respectively:
$$
\begin{align*}
(x,y,z) &= ( u \cos(v), u \sin(v), f(u,v) ) \\
(x,y,z) &= ( u \cos(v), u \sin(v), g(u,v) )
\end{align*}
$$
I had tried and got results with $f(u)$ and $g(v)$ only in either case with standard method.

But when $u,v$ are appearing for $z$, I require guidance.

Comment: Is there some particular reason you're using polar coordinates rather than Cartesian? Just write out the Christoffel symbols and use the Gauss equation.

Comment: A deviation from rotational symmetry would perhaps result in simpler form to compare with special cases sphere/pseudosphere and be amenable to numerical computation/visualization. In particular, Daina Taimina's crocheted surfaces (and the likes of the same in minimal surfaces also) do not have a known differential equation description with BC afaik upto this point of time..mathematical modeling seems to lag behind already  realized physical models here.